# Base de datos con Laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, tablas

soy super nuevo en esto de laravel y en esta comunidad, quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar con una instrucción super fácil al parecer pero que por algún motivo no he podido encontrar....

-Cuándo hago la validación básica atreves del comando artisan auth... automáticamente me selecciona la tabla users creada por las migraciones básicas de laravel, ¿Cómo o donde se puede seleccionar otra tabla?, es decir, no quiero usar Users... quiero usar la tabla Cliente. (ambas tablas ya creadas con sus columnas y todo lo necesario...)

de ante mano muchas gracias <3

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Nos ayudaría mucho ver lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Explica bien que comandos ejecutas y todo lo que tenes configurado para que te puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno para configurar las autenticaciones puedes hacerlo revisando la carpeta config, dentro están los archivos de configuraciones, no recuerdo bien y no tengo un proyecto a la mano pero estaria seguro que ahí un archivo auth.php en esa carpeta bueno ese debe tener las configurado el modelo User con el cual viene la aplicación y esas es la forma como autentica, si lo haces con otra tabla bueno solo remplaza por el modelo y asegúrate de agregar a ese modelo todas las extensiones y traits que tiene el modelo user para que te funciones.

Una tutorial bien explicado lo puede encontrar en [este enlace](https://aprendible.com)

Comment: muuchas gracias me sirvió muuucho <3